# Private Route React router always redirects to first Route

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-router

Actually I had no problem with directing to another route by clicking a button, but somehow I can't direct manually by changing the URL. Every time I was about changing the URL (ex: localhost:3000/proposal), it always directs me to the first `Route`. Here's the Route in order :

```
<Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} /> // => always goin here
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />

                  {/* Dashboard */}
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/home"
                    component={Home}
                    StickyNav={StickyNavbar}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/proposal"
                    component={Proposal}
                    StickyNav={StickyNavbar}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    exact
                    path="/laporan"
                    component={Laporan}
                    StickyNav={StickyNavbar}
                  />

                  <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
```

It doesn't direct me to `Landing` if I change the URL to non-private route. Here's my private route code :

```
import React from "react"
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
})

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} {...rest} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
)

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your auth object initialized in time of that check when accessing page initially?

Comment: yeah it should be there. I've seen it on Redux devTools and it's `.isAuthenticated = true`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @zhuber said, the auth object from react-redux doesn't call before the private route was called. So I changed the condition from `isAuthenticated` using localStorage like this :

```
      !isEmpty(localStorage.jwtToken) ? (
        <Component {...props} {...rest} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
```

Comment: In such cases you can use loading component where you use your auth.loading bool and show loader when auth is being initialized, and then execute logic above when loading is false.

Comment: I'm actually using React lazyload and App.js is wrapped inside `React.suspense`, but I don't know why the loader is showing but it suddenly direct to `Landing`.